# CMOS and Pseudo NMOS

Tags: cmos, nmos

Im trying design this function : (NOT Y)=A+BCD in CMOS my design in pic below now i want to design this function in Pseudo NMOS but i dont know how to design it in Pseudo NMOS.anyone can help please??[image]

Comment: It won't work without a pull-up resistor.

Comment: @Andyaka how i add a pull-up resistor?

Comment: A pull-up resistor is a resistor which will pull up (make high) the output when all transistors which could pull the output down (low) are **off**. Now think where this resistor must be placed. Hint: one side of the resistor must connect to VDD, the supply voltage (which is invisible in your schematic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The name ``pseudo-NMOS'' originates from the circumstance that in the
>   older NMOS technologies a depletion mode NMOS transistor with its gate
>   connected to source was used as a pull-up device.
>    http://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/schrom/node101.html

Pseudo-NMOS isn't totem pole output, just add a small PMOS pull-up.

Note: Depletion mode refers to the channel being inverted at Vgs = 0, similar to a typical JFET, you use the gate to pull the device out of conduction.